# Кривая печать из webbrowser

Tags: c#, html, css, печать

Вывожу html шаблон в элемент управления webbrowser.
[image: html документ в webbrowser]

Все красиво. ПКМ - Предварительный просмотр и и вот результат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ширину и высоту столбцов задал в сантиметрах. В остальных браузерах все в порядке. Даже в эксплорере выводит на печать хорошо. В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: кажется причина в том, что при печати css не учитывается, но как заставить учитывать?

Comment: уберите `srink to fit` в настройках предпросмотра, перестанет растягивать по высоте и ширине, дальше подставьте правильные размеры

Comment: @rdorn - причина не в этом

Comment: Сантиметры не очень хорошая ширина для компьютера

Comment: @Duoxx указал в процентах. реально оставить ксс?

Answer (score 0):

убрал ширину и высоту CSS. задал её в процентах.